# onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer} is not showing drawernavigation in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Below i have added all files code and my question is when i press Login button from Login.js it goes to Home.js and there i need DrawerNavigation which i have created in drawer.js but when i use onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer} inside Home.js drawer is not  opening can anyone help me please please see below link to view output

[Login.js Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nWaH.jpg)

[Home.js Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE0Az.jpg)

```
navigation
   -index.js
   -drawer.js
screen
   -Login.js
   -Home.js
   -Signup.js
App.js
```

This is navigation/index.js

```js
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import Login from "../screens/Login";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Signup from "../screens/Signup";
import { theme } from "../constants";

const screens = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login,
    Home,
    Signup,
    
  },

  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
     
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(screens);
```

this is screens/Login.js

```js
export default class Login extends Component {
  
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
           <Button
              style={styles.signin}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}>
              <Text style={styles.buttontext}>Login</Text>
            </Button>

    );
  }
}
```

this is drawer.js

```js
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation-drawer";

import {
  ProfileScreen,
  EducationalScreen,
  ExperienceScreen,
  MessageScreen,
  ActivityScreen,
  LogoutScreen,
} from "./Screen";

import SideBar from "../components/SideBar";

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    ProfileScreen,
    EducationalScreen,
    ExperienceScreen,
    MessageScreen,
    ActivityScreen,
    LogoutScreen,
  },

  {
    contentComponent: (props) => <SideBar {...props} />,
  }
  
);
export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

This is navigation/Home.js

```js
export default class Screen extends React.Component {
                 
                 render() {
                   const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
                   return (
                     <View style={styles.container}>
                       <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                         <TouchableOpacity
                           style={{ alignItems: "flex-end", margin: 16 }}
                           onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer}
                         >
                           <FontAwesome5
                             name="bars"
                             size={24}
                             colors="#161924"
                           />
                         </TouchableOpacity>
                         <View
                           style={{
                             flex: 1,
                             alignItems: "center",
                             justifyContent: "center",
                           }}
                         >
                         </View>
                       </SafeAreaView>
                     </View>
                   );
                 }
               }
```

here is the App.js Code

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  
    return (
      <Block>
        <Navigation />
        
        </Block>
        
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot in your code blocks that doesn't need to be there, like imports, exports, CSS etc. Only show the minimal relevant code. Also, the specific `onPress` code in your title/description isn't in the actual code anywhere. Plus it looks like it contains a syntax error, shouldn't there be parentheses after the function name? i.e. `onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}`

Comment: thank you very much for your time @Jayce444 
-i agree i have created custom components that is why i have more blocks.              -sorry i forgot to add home.js code where i used onPress now you can see.          -if i use openDrawer() error is ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Screen.props.navigation') ``` so i just added onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer} thank you for your time i hope i gave some useful information to get you an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your `App.js` look like? Make sure that you only have one **root navigator**. You have to nest either the `DrawerNavigator` inside the `StackNavigator` or vice versa.

Depending on how your Navigation should work, I would recommend you to create the `DrawerNavigator` as `RootNavigator` and nest the `StackNavigator` inside it. That way, you have the possibility to call the `openDrawer` function inside the `StackScreens` as it refers to the parent navigator.

See Docs [React Navigation - Nesting Navigators](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators)

Edit:

navigation/index.js (no drawer.js needed that way)

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import *Screens from '../screens/*';

const StackNav = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Login: LoginScreen,
  SignUp: SignUpScreen
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {...}
})

const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Profile: ProfileScreen,
  Educational: EducationalScreen,
  Stack: StackNav
}, {
  defaultNavigationOptions: {...}
})

const Navigation = createAppContainer(DrawerNav)

export default Navigation
```

I'm not sure if that above nesting is correct for your app flow.
[Nesting Drawer Navigators inside others](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/drawer-navigator/#nesting-drawer-navigators-inside-others)

Comment: Thank you @Maximilian Kaske 
i tried to create drawer navigator inside stack but when i export it its says you can only export one. check above i have added app.js code please help us

Comment: @ChandraSekharMalla take a look at the edited answer. Hope it is useful